# Issue, Receipt and Balance from MySql table

Tags: mysql, join, sum, sql-order-by

I have two tables, issue and receipt where I am issuing and receiving quantities :

### IssueTable:

| Order | Type | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OD12 | A | 48 |
| OD19 | A | 33 |
| OD12 | B | 14 |

### ReceiptTable:

| Order | Type | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OD12 | A | 20 |
| OD19 | A | 15 |
| OD12 | B | 11 |

The desired result that I want:

### Balance:

| Order | Type | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OD12 | A | 28 |
| OD19 | A | 18 |
| OD12 | B | 03 |

IssueTable contains details of Orders which have been issued, a single order can have multiple "Type" of products. Similarly, ReceiptTable contains details of Orders which have been completed and received. I want a Balance table which subtracts issue qty from receipt qty based on Order and Type.

Comment: Does `(Order,Type)` defines the instance? is it unique over each separate table? Why `Qty` for `(OD12, A)` is 24, not 28?

Comment: @Akina it is 28, was a typo error

Comment: Does `(Order,Type)` is unique over each separate table? Does some external table with all possible pairs values exists, ot these pairs list must be gathered from the above tables?

Comment: Order and Type are gathered from a userform. Type is selected from a group of products [A,R,C,D,etc]

Comment: I mean the next: does it is possible that some `(Order,Type)` pair is present in one table but is absent in another?

Comment: @Akina yes, for example - OD15, Type C and R with Qty 44 and 11 respectively are issued but none have been received yet. so it is present in IssueTable but not in ReceiptTable. In this case, the BalanceTable should show the full quantity i.e 44 and 11.

Comment: Is it possible the backward situation - the pair value is present in ReceiptTable but not in IssueTable?

Comment: @Akina yes, possible. but the "order" number would be NULL. meaning the balances are of those orders that have "OD*" present in "order"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT `Order`, 
       `Type`, 
       COALESCE(IssueTable.Qty, 0) - COALESCE(ReceiptTable.Qty, 0) Qty
FROM ( SELECT `Order`, `Type` FROM IssueTable
       UNION 
       SELECT `Order`, `Type` FROM ReceiptTable ) TotalTable
LEFT JOIN IssueTable USING (`Order`, `Type`)
LEFT JOIN ReceiptTable USING (`Order`, `Type`);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cafd416abcbf7ab31f54bf6efbd6566f

The query assumes that `(Order, Type)` is unique in each separate table. If not then use aggreagating subqueries instead if the tables itself.

Comment: How to get "Total Issued Qty" and "Total Received Qty" then "Balance Qty" for the same above format

Comment: I am getting a different result https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e2092337197bc08c5b16bd2157a70f4e

Comment: @crazyboy24 In your data `(Order, Type)` is not unique. As I have said, aggregate before joining.

Comment: by aggregate do you mean GROU BY?

Comment: @crazyboy24 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=703e57abcde93b59c678ec43aa224787

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a join approach:

```sql
SELECT it.`Order`, it.Type, it.Qty - rt.Qty AS Qty
FROM IssueTable it
INNER JOIN ReceiptTable rt
    ON rt.`Order` = it.`Order` AND rt.Type = it.Type;
```

This answer assumes that every order would have a matching receipt.  If not, the approach might have to change slightly based on your expectations.  As a side note, `ORDER` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, and you should avoid naming your columns and tables using it.